# using itoa with an integer . Setting limits of a buffer

Tags: c++, c++11

I was going over this example using `itoa` and wanted to know more about the statement

```
char buffer [sizeof(int)*8+1];
```

why did the author do `[sizeof(int)*8+1]`?  I understand `sizeof(int)` but why did the author do `*8+1`?

This is the code

```
#define _OPEN_SYS_ITOA_EXT
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
   int i;
   char buffer [sizeof(int)*8+1];
   printf ("Enter a number: ");
   if (scanf ("%d",&i) == 1) {
      itoa (i,buffer,DECIMAL);
      printf ("decimal: %s\n",buffer);
      itoa (i,buffer,HEX);
      printf ("hexadecimal: %s\n",buffer);
      itoa (i,buffer,OCTAL);
      printf ("octal: %s\n",buffer);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I got this example from [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/itoa.htm)

Comment: Typically a +1 is for a NUL terminator for the string, but the sizeof() part strikes me as strange honestly.  Max int on 32-bit system is in single digit billions - so 10 digits.  For 64-bits, 2^64, log 10 is 20 digits.  Even octal, base 8, is going to be smaller than that size of.  Hence, strange.

Comment: I got it from here https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxbd00/itoa.htm

Comment: I can think of reasoning for `char buffer [sizeof(int)*3.4+3];`, but not `*8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have an `int` then the number of binary digits it has is `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`.  Since generally `CHAR_BIT` is 8 and as long as it is then `char buffer [sizeof(int)*8+1];` will make a bufffer that can store ever binary digit and the terminating null character you need for a valid c-string.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up on a side note will the above example also work for converting int32_t ? Will this suffice `sizeof(int32_t)*8+1` ?

Comment: Ok, safety for binary numbers makes sense.  The example used octal, but if they wanted to switch to binary, then nice no changes needed, no phantom buffer overruns.

Comment: @Rajeshwar Yes.  Ideally you should use `char buffer [sizeof(some_type)*CHAR_BIT+1];` to be completely safe.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Yeah, even though the author didn't use binary using the value they did guarantees it will work in case they ever do.

Comment: When i try this example out I am getting the error "Use of undeclared identifier DECIMAL" does DECIMAL need a specific header ? can I use std::dec instead ?

Comment: @Rajeshwar I'm not 100% sure.  `itoa` takes a integer for the last parameter so most likely in the example there is a `define DECIMAL 10` some where in the headers.  You can just replace the text with the value to get it to compile.

Comment: From [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/), the last parameter is the "*Numerical base used to represent the value as a string, between 2 and 36, where 10 means decimal base, 16 hexadecimal, 8 octal, and 2 binary*".

Answer (score -1):

This is C-style strings. Those strings are null-terminated. For instance the string "Hello" will contain the characters 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' and '\0'.

The +1 is for the null character '\0'.